# Reactjs: How to display one toggled content at a time on button click

Tags: reactjs

The code below was used to toggle content on button click and it works excellent as their respective contents gets displayed for each clicked button.

**Here is what I want to implement.**

Now I have the task of displaying one collapse content record on button click.

Here is what I mean, when I click on the first button, the content will be toggled and displayed.

when I click on the second button, I want to be seeing only the content of the second clicked button while hidding the
content of the first and so on.  Thanks

**Here is the code so far**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shown: true,
 shown1: true,
 shown2: true,
 shown3: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
    });
  }



toggle1() {
        this.setState({
            shown1: !this.state.shown1
        });
    }



toggle2() {
        this.setState({
            shown2: !this.state.shown2
        });
    }



toggle3() {
        this.setState({
            shown3: !this.state.shown3
        });
    }



  render() {

var shown = {
            display: this.state.shown ? "block" : "none"
        };

        var hidden1 = {
            display: this.state.shown1 ? "none" : "block"
        }
        var hidden2 = {
            display: this.state.shown2 ? "none" : "block"
        }
        var hidden3 = {
            display: this.state.shown3 ? "none" : "block"
        }




  return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>


<button onClick={this.toggle1.bind(this)}>Toggle 1</button>
<button onClick={this.toggle2.bind(this)}>Toggle 2</button>
<button onClick={this.toggle3.bind(this)}>Toggle 3</button>

            <h2 style={ hidden1 }> Toggle record 1 appears Here</h2>
            <h2 style={ hidden2 }> Toggle record 2 appears Here</h2>
            <h2 style={ hidden3 }> Toggle record 3 appears Here</h2>
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored it a little bit. You can apply some css to make the content collapse.

import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shownId: undefined
    };
  }

  toggle(id) {
    this.setState({
      shownId: id
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <ul>
            <button onClick={() => this.toggle(1)}>Toggle 1</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.toggle(2)}>Toggle 2</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.toggle(3)}>Toggle 3</button>

            <h2
              style={{ display: this.state.shownId === 1 ? "block" : "none" }}>Toggle record 1 appears Here
            </h2>
            <h2
              style={{ display: this.state.shownId === 2 ? "block" : "none" }}>Toggle record 2 appears Here
            </h2>
            <h2
              style={{ display: this.state.shownId === 3 ? "block" : "none" }}>Toggle record 3 appears Here
            </h2>
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/m9jxw7rk0p)